# Prevent keyboard from poping up in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, keyboard

I am developing a website that will run mainly on iPad devices (iOS 6) I have a custom built on screen keyboard built using HTML, CSS and Javscript. My keyboard will put information into an input field. Is it possible using *only* HTML, CSS, or JS to prevent the default iOS keyboad from appearing?

Please know this is a website only not an app. I can only use HTML, CSS, and Javascript. No Server Side Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `readonly="true"` on your input field to stop the iOS keyboard from popping up. Make sure you only do this for iOS devices, else users on other devices won't be able to interact with your forms.